# what is the relationship between NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT, indexed view and Insert/delete/update operations?

Tags: sql-server

May be somebody can explain WHY we can't make insert/delete/update on the table with  `NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON` if the table participates in the indexed view (we should set `NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF`) ?

I mean why Microsoft programmed it this way, what is the background of the decision? May be there are side effects or something in architecture prevent to ignore `NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT`..

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of MSDN documentation, that can be found @ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx

"`SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT` must be `OFF` when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT` is `ON`, `CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE` statements on tables with indexes on computed columns or indexed views will fail. For more information about required `SET` option settings with indexed views and indexes on computed columns, see "Considerations When You Use the `SET` Statements" in [`SET` Statements (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx)."

You will have to ask Microsoft programmer as to why it was done exactly.

My take on it: this is done to prevent index from failing because is not setup to handle errors that come up when `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON`

Comment: Could you explain it: "My take on it: this is done to prevent index from failing because is not setup to handle errors that come up when SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON" ? What kind of round operation can be used during reindexing?